# Value elements class for Date time format

Tags: simulation, anylogic

My data is of following format (Arrival times), then what should be the "Value elements class" in the LinkedHashMap Collections for column Arrival times?

[Input table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEcXp.png)

Comment: Basically, I want to store the second column into the collections at the model startup. Please guide

Comment: you don't need a LinkedHashMap. Use an arrayList

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to this question, but from your other question I am getting an impression that you're doing this to create a number of entities that are emitted from the Source component on schedule.

If this is the case then you're in luck as Source component has an option to set arrival based on a table of date/time values. You can see more in the help documentation [here](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fprocessmodeling%2Fsource.html&resultof=%22%73%6f%75%72%63%65%22%20%22%73%6f%75%72%63%22%20) and that page also has a link to an example model that shows how to use it.